# Default Empty Value for Html.DropDownList()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a dropdown list like so:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Segments", String.Empty)
```

and populating it with ViewBag.Segments

This particular overload of Html.DropDownList creates a blank entry at the top of the list, with no value. When the dropdown list doesn't have a selected segment, it defaults to the first item in the list (with value 1) rather than the blank entry (no value).

The HTML renders as:

```
<select id="foo" name="foo">
  <option value></option>
  <option selected="selected" value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
```

Is there a way I can get it to default to the blank item?

Comment: Can you post how do you fill in the `ViewBag.Segments`?

Comment: ViewBag.Segments is an IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Comment: Do you have a `Segments` named action parameter or route parameter or property on your Model? Because it seems something fills in already the dropdown with a selected value... debug your controller action and check the value of `ModelState["Segments"].Value`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Html helper havent finished method overload DropDownList whitch u want. U can create List that you need. Something like that:

```
List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
list.add(new SelectListItem(){ Value="", Key = 0});
foreach(var item in Repositury){
   list.add(new SelectListItem(){ Value=item.value, Key = item.key});
}
ViewBag.list = list;
```

After use DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Segments", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.list)
```

Comment: His problem is not lacking a blank item rather having it selected by default.

Comment: So actually this led me to the correct answer. This combined with leaving the String.Empty optionLabel out of the Html.DropDownList("Segments") worked.